# How to check a textbox and redirect to an URL with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm trying to make a 'password protected' page for the pages that I build for customers, so that they can check the progress of their page, but it won't be available for people who don't have a code.

I've been trying a few hours now but i can't seem to get it working. I can get a popup screen now with a place with the login code, but I can't make it redirect to another page.

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.accesbutton').click(function() {
    $('.login').fadeIn('fast');
    $('.opening').fadeTo('fast', 0.2);
  });

  var $code = $('.logincode').val();
  var $check = 'DDT4DHFD';
  $('.submit').click(function() {
    if ($code === $check) {
      window.location = 'homepage.html';
    } else {
      $('.logincode').animate({
        color: 'red'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.login {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 1em;
  left: 35%;
  top: 10em;
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
}
.accesbutton {
  background-color: #FF3333;
  width: 10em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3em;
  margin: 2em auto;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
.text {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <html>
  <div class="accesbutton">
    <p class="text">Bekijk website</p>
  </div>
  <div class="login">
    <p class="text" style="color:#000000">Je kunt hier inloggen met een toeganscode.
      <br>
      <br>Heb je geen toegangscode? Neem dan contact op met The Design Company of je Beheerder.
      <br>
    </p>
    <p class="text" style="color:#000000">
      <label for="usermail">Toegangscode:</label>
      <input type="text" name="usercode" placeholder="XXXXXXXX" class="logincode" required>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" class="submit">
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Some of the text is in dutch, including the button.

The first part opens the pop up screen, and the second part should redirect to the page when the code is correct.

What am I doing wrong?

-Johr Claessens

Comment: be aware: client-side (i.e., implemented in javascript) authentication like this is very trivially bypassed.

Comment: The websites that I work on right now aren't really that big of a deal if they get bypassed. It's only to keep the most people away who already check the website when it isn't officialy launched. But good to know, i'll keep that in mind ;)

Comment: Change the submit to type="button" and move `var $check=$....` Inside the click function

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

For security issues you may use [get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) or [post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) using as data parameter   $('.logincode').val().  On server side (using your current language  like C#, javascript, PHP, ... I don't know which one you currently use) you can compare the values and return to the client side only a value: true or false. As example you may write something like:

```
$.get("checklogin.php", { val: $('.logincode').val() } )
 .done(function(data) {})
 .fail(function() {});
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

The typo in your code is:

```
var $code = $('.logincode').val();
```

This is declared outside the event handler.

I may suggest you to save the value of the variable $check on the server side, this is a little an simple trick, in order to avoid to have such a variable visible on the client side:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.accesbutton').click(function() {
    $('.login').fadeIn('fast');
    $('.opening').fadeTo('fast', 0.2);
  });


  var $check = 'DDT4DHFD'; // put this variable in a text (or json) file on server side
  $('.submit').click(function(e) {
    var $code = $('.logincode').val();  // this is your typo
    
    
    // you may use this to get and test value from your server
    // I figured out checklogin as a text server side file
    /***************************
    $('.submit').prop('disabled', true);
    $.get('checklogin', function( data ) {
      if (data.trim() == $check) {
        window.location = 'homepage.html';
      } else {
        $('.logincode').animate({
          color: 'red'
        });
      }
      $(this).removeProp('disabled');
    }).fail(function() {
      console.log('Failed');
      $('.submit').removeProp('disabled');
    });
    ****************************/
    // Till here.........................
    
    
    // or like you are doing.....
    if ($code === $check) {
      window.location = 'homepage.html';
    } else {
      $('.logincode').animate({
        color: 'red'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.login {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 1em;
  left: 35%;
  top: 10em;
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
}
.accesbutton {
  background-color: #FF3333;
  width: 10em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3em;
  margin: 2em auto;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
.text {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="accesbutton">
    <p class="text">Bekijk website</p>
</div>
<div class="login">
    <p class="text" style="color:#000000">Je kunt hier inloggen met een toeganscode.
        <br>
        <br>Heb je geen toegangscode? Neem dan contact op met The Design Company of je Beheerder.
        <br>
    </p>
    <p class="text" style="color:#000000">
        <label for="usermail">Toegangscode:</label>
        <input type="text" name="usercode" placeholder="XXXXXXXX" class="logincode" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="submit">
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I'm going to try the Server sided method later this week. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @johrclaessens fyi, putting the passphrase on a file on the server still won't provide any security. anyone can view the javascript code that opens the file, take note of what file is being opened, and simply open the file themselves and read the contents. or they can open the developer tools and change the string comparison to say `if (1 === 1)` to bypass the check entirely.

Comment: The passphrase in JS issue was already addressed in the comments on the question itself above